# How to use AssistiveTouch UI in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I'm now developing an app on iOS. With some reason, I want to use AssistiveTouch UI in my app. For example, there will display a button in my app like AssistiveTouch, if anyone press this button, four buttons will appear like AssistiveTouch, if anyone press one of there four buttons again, some action i set before will excuse.

Does apple support api about this? Or Is there any source code available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to reimplement this from scratch. There is no public API for either accessing the existing Assistive Touch feature (it has to be turned on by the user in the settings) or for creating a similar UI.

Comment: thank you for your answer, e... is there any open source project about this available? or is there any source code about this available?